# How to do this recursion relation in Mathematica effectively?

Tags: functions, series-expansion, recursion

I have a function $h_{\Delta,l}(r,\eta)$ satisfying
\begin{equation}
h_{\Delta,l}(r,\eta)=\tilde{h}_{l}(r,\eta)+\sum_{k}\frac{c(k)}{\Delta-(1-l-k)}r^{k}h_{1-l+k,l+k}(r,\eta)
\end{equation}
where $k$ are integers and
\begin{equation}\tilde{h}_l(r,\eta)=\frac{g_l(\eta)}{(1-r^2)^a (1+r^2+2r \eta)^b}\end{equation}
with $a$ and $b$ being some known parameters.

I want to find the series expansion of $h_{\Delta,l}(r,\eta)$ up to order $r^{20}$.

My strategy was to use recursion relation to expand the $h_{\Delta,l}(r,\eta)$ in terms of $r^{a_1} h_{a_2,a_3}(r,\eta)$ up to $a=20$ at first, then do the series expansion of $h_{a_2,a_3}(r,\eta)$ and read off all terms inside $h_{\Delta,l}(r,\eta)$ with the right power. To implement this idea in a brute-force way is painful. Any suggestions?

Comment: hmmm...i feel as though there might be some info or constraint missing here. As written, it seems as though $n_i$ (and $\Delta_i$ and $l_i$) is independent of $i$, and dependent only on $k$ and $l$. And it's not clear what "for all possible $i$" means; could we have $i \in I$ for any index set $I$, or do we know the index set we're using here?

Comment: @thorimur  You are absolutely right. There are actually three different structures here for i. To simplify the question, I only put one structure there but didn't explain it well. I edited the question, maybe it's more readable now.

Comment: Do you have a base case? $\Delta = l=1$?

Comment: @MikeY Let's say $\Delta=5.509, l=2$ as an example